# Java - Partially convert 2D string to 2D Integer ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I was trying to convert my 2D String into 2D Integer ArrayList, but I don't know how to. I have read some reference but didn't find anything related.

Here is my method:

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> convert2DStringTo2DIntArrayList(String[][] originalString, int lengthOfRow, int lengthOfColumn) {
    ArrayList<int[]> targetList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    if (lengthOfRow == -1) {
        lengthOfRow = originalString.length - 1;
    }
    if (lengthOfColumn == -1) {
        lengthOfColumn = originalString[0].length - 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= lengthOfRow - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= lengthOfColumn - 1; j++) {

            //targetList.addAll(Integer.parseInt(Arrays.asList(originalString)));
        }
    }
    return targetList;
}
```

When lengthOfRow and lengthOfColumn all equal to -1 this method will fully convert 2D String to 2D Integer ArrayList. No problem with String because the String array to be proceed is partially filled by integer. I met this problem is because my original methods are all written in basic types and string. On the mid way I found I cannot handle several problem with string array. By this reason I have to write several method to convert string to ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated.** To convert multidimensional array of integers represented as strings:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Convert
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> list = convert2DStringToList(new String[][]{ {"0", "1", "2"}, {"3", "4", "5"}, {"100", "200", "300", "500"}, {"22"} });
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> convert2DStringToList(String[][] original)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++)
        {
            List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(subList);
            for (int j = 0; j < original[i].length; j++)
            {
                subList.add(Integer.valueOf(original[i][j]));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

For given code the output is [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [100, 200, 300, 500], [22]].

Comment: The question is to convert 2D string array to 2D Integer array NOT 1D Integer array !!

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that can help you.

```
public void ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> convert2DStringTo2DIntegerArray(String[][] original) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> tempArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int j = 0; j < original[i].length; j++)
            {
                tempArray.add(Integer.valueOf(original[i][j]));
            }
            list.add(tempArray);
        }
    return list;
}
```